# Valid Adobe Scene7 URL yields 'Error loading player: No playable sources found'

Tags: javascript, html, video, adobe, jwplayer

Creating an app that injects Scene7 videos into a JWPlayer script, but it appears the JWPlayer is unable to play the video URL despite the URL itself links directly to the video, this could possibly be because Scene7 isn't giving me a video URL ending in .mp4 etc.

Below is the relating code snippet:

```html
<script src="https://jwpsrv.com/library/6qcWCLNWEeS4Ig4AfQhyIQ.js"></script><div id="jwplayer_gK8G1wBJrmNLGlA">Loading the player...</div><script type="text/javascript">jwplayer('jwplayer_gK8G1wBJrmNLGlA').setup({
"sources": [
{
"file": "https://sonyglobal.scene7.com/is/content/gwtvid/MDR-100AAP_Lifestyle-Video_1280x720_2000K",
"label": "sd"
},
{
"file": "https://sonyglobal.scene7.com/is/content/gwtvid/MDR-100AAP_Lifestyle-Video_1280x720_2000K",
"label": "hd"
},
{
"file": "https://sonyglobal.scene7.com/is/content/gwtvid/MDR-100AAP_Lifestyle-Video_1280x720_2000K",
"label": "hls"
},
{
"file": "https://sonyglobal.scene7.com/is/content/gwtvid/MDR-100AAP_Lifestyle-Video_1280x720_2000K",
"label": "mobile"
}
],
"width": 640,
"height": 360
});</script>
```

Any idea why this does not work? If it is due to there being no file extension. Is there a way to show it on Adobe Scene7's side?

Thanks,
Charlie

Answer (score 2):

If you know your file is in a supported format, you can use the type configuration option to force the player to recognize the file as being of that format. See the Configuration Options Reference for more info.

https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413113-configuration-options-reference

playlist[].sources[].type
Media type of the source. Is only needed when the file property does not contain a recognized file extension (like .mp4 for mp4). The Media Formats Reference lists all supported types.

https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-reference

Comment: Hi Josie, I checked up on what you had said and the links you gave me. I reminded me to define the video link as a type since it had no file extension in the name. A quick "type": ".mp4" solved it. Thanks a ton for your help! :)